# Doing a join on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 sql tables

1) a table with headers of a coupon - id of this equals the id of the second table

2) a tables with details of the coupon - user_id on this tables equals user id of the third table

3) a table with details of user

So far I have this query

```
"SELECT kpn_processed_deals.kpn_id,
kpn_processed_deals.purchased_date, kpn_processed_deals.claim, 
kpn_processed_deals.uid,kpn_deal_headers.kpn_type,
kpn_deal_headers.title,kpn_deal_headers.created_by
 FROM kpn_processed_deals INNER JOIN kpn_deal_headers ON
 kpn_processed_deals.kpn_id = kpn_deal_headers.kpn_id AND 
kpn_deal_headers.created_by = '$var'";
```

This works just fine but I want to get the value of the users email on the third table using a join but I have been unsuccessful so far. Sorry if my formatting is messy. I'm horrible at these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `JOIN`.

```
"SELECT p.kpn_id, p.purchased_date, p.claim, p.uid,h.kpn_type, h.title, h.created_by, u.email
 FROM kpn_processed_deals AS p INNER
 JOIN kpn_deal_headers AS h ON p.kpn_id = h.kpn_id
 JOIN kpn_deal_users AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
 WHERE h.created_by = '$var'";
```

Also notice the use of table aliases, so you don't have to repeat the verbose table names throughout the query.

And constraints on single tables should normally be in the `WHERE` clause; the `ON` clause is for conditions related to joining the tables (an exception is in outer joins, where constraints on the child table need to be in the `ON` clause as well).

Comment: Man!! you are my hero. Thanks a lot

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to point out your use of aliases - they make it hella more readable ;)

Comment: @ShadowScripter Don't know why im scared of aliases...:P